# How can you read a file line by line in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, ipad, file-io

I'm writing a web-app for the iPad that will be loading data from a text file. (A sample data set is around ~400 kb). I have everything set up except the file reading. The way I have set up my code, you pass an object which reads a file line by line.

How can I read a file line by line?

If there is no direct way to read a file line by line, can someone please show me an example of how to read a file into a string object? (so that I can use the split method :P)

Comment: What kind of file? From a URL? From the device?

Comment: A plaintext file. From a URL is fine.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This could work, if I understood what you want to do:

```
var txtFile = new XMLHttpRequest();
txtFile.open("GET", "http://website.com/file.txt", true);
txtFile.onreadystatechange = function()
{
  if (txtFile.readyState === 4) {  // document is ready to parse.
    if (txtFile.status === 200) {  // file is found
      allText = txtFile.responseText; 
      lines = txtFile.responseText.split("\n");
    }
  }
}
txtFile.send(null);
```

Comment: It sends the request, not the file. At this moment the file is not received yet. The `null` argument, which could be omitted in this case, means that you do not upload any file to the server.

Comment: @awerti Thank you! It works! I had to shuffle around and rearrange my program, but I got the file reading to work.

Comment: How do you get one line at a time through EOF in a loop?

Comment: that comment is in a function called "myfunction()" in my code but when i run it it says "myfunction is undefined ?"

Answer (score 2):

Mobile Safari doesn't have the [File API](http://www.w3.org/TR/FileAPI/), so I assume you're talking about reading from a web resource. You can't do that. When you read a resource via ajax, the browser will first read it fully into memory and then pass the entire string to your ajax callback as a string.

In your callback, you can take the string and break it into lines, and wrap that up in an object that has the API that your code wants, but you're still going to have the string in memory all at once..

Comment: Is a 400 kb file reasonable for iPad memory?

Comment: @Ryan: Well, the first generation iPad has 256M = 262,656k of RAM. 400k is less than two tenths of one percent of that (~0.15%). I have no idea how much of it Mobile Safari is allowed to use, though. You'll have to try it out and see. And of course, be careful not to end up making lots of copies of the string once you've read it...

Comment: It's more about the memory allocated to Mobile Safari. Many applications greatly limit the memory allocated to JS.

Comment: @Ryan: Hence *"I have no idea how much of it Mobile Safari is allowed to use, though."* ;-)

Answer (score 2):

With jQuery:

```
myObject = {}; //myObject[numberline] = "textEachLine";
$.get('path/myFile.txt', function(myContentFile) {
   var lines = myContentFile.split("\r\n");

   for(var i  in lines){
      //here your code
      //each line is "lines[i]"

      //save in object "myObject": 
      myObject[i] = lines[i]

      //print in console
      console.log("line " + i + " :" + lines[i]);
   }
}, 'text');
```

Comment: This would work. It does require JQuery though, which is relatively common, but it is still a caveat to consider. I was not using JQuery in that project.

Answer (score 0):

i dont think thats possible until you use ajax to hit some server side code.

Comment: Well, I found a FileReader object: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/FileReader. Unfortunately, it reads the entire file and I'm confused on how to use it. I think it is possible, if such an object exists and does what I think it does (read a file).

Comment: @Ryan: See my answer. `FileReader` is part of the File API, which Mobile Safari does not support.