# In concatenated result set: Error: [XPTY0004] Single item expected, (element x { … }, element x { … }, …) found

Tags: xml-parsing, xquery

I found that the following code worked on a small set of my data, but I didn't realize that I hadn't taken any samples with multiple comments.  When I tried to apply the code to the actual database, which has multiple comments per entry, I received the error mentioned above.

Current code:

```
for $doc in doc('test')
let $results :=
(
  let $pKeywords := ('best clients', 'Very', '20')
  return
    for $kw in $pKeywords
    return
    (
      $doc/set/entry[contains(comment, concat('!', $kw))],
      $doc/set/entry[contains(comment, $kw)]
    )
  [not(position() gt 2)]
)
for $i in (1 to count($results))
return
(
  subsequence($results/comment, $i, 1),
  subsequence($results/buyer, $i, 1)
)
```

Document:

```
<set>
  <entry>
    <comment>The client is only 20 years old.  Do not be surprised by his youth.</comment>
    <buyer></buyer>
    <id>1282</id>
    <industry>International Trade; Fish and Game</industry>
  </entry>
  <entry>
    <comment>!On leave in October.</comment>
    <comment>!Planning to make a large purchase before Christmas.</comment>
    <buyer></buyer>
    <id>709</id>
    <industry>Real Estate</industry>
  </entry>
    <entry>
    <comment>Is often !out between 1 and 3 p.m.</comment>
    <buyer></buyer>
    <id>127</id>
    <industry>Virus Software Marketting</industry>
  </entry>
  <entry>
    <comment>Very personable.  One of our best clients.</comment>
    <buyer></buyer>
    <id>14851</id>
    <industry>Administrative support.</industry>
  </entry>
  <entry>
    <comment>!Very difficult to reach, but one of our top buyers.</comment>
    <comment>His wife often answers the phone.  That means he is out of the office.</comment>
    <buyer></buyer>
    <id>1458</id>
    <industry>Construction</industry>
  </entry>
  <entry>
    <comment></comment>
    <buyer></buyer>
    <id>276470</id>
    <industry>Bulk Furniture Sales</industry>
  </entry>
  <entry>
    <comment>A bit of an eccentric.  One of our best clients.</comment>
    <buyer></buyer>
    <id>1506</id>
    <industry>Sports Analysis</industry>
  </entry>
  <entry>
    <comment>Very gullible, so please !be sure she needs what you sell her.  She's one of our best clients.</comment>
    <buyer></buyer>
    <id>1523</id>
    <industry>International Trade</industry>
  </entry>
  <entry>
    <comment>He wants to buy everything, but !he has a tight budget.</comment>
    <comment>!His company may be closing soon.</comment>
    <buyer></buyer>
    <id>1524</id>
    <industry>Public Relations</industry>
  </entry>
</set>
```

The result:

```
Stopped at line 9, column 22: [XPTY0004] document-node()(...): function(item()*) as item()* expected, document-node() found.
```

I ran into a similar error and was able to fix it, but when I try to apply the fixes, that did not work.  Example:

```
  $doc('test')/set/entry[contains(., concat('!', $kw))],
  $doc('test')/set/entry[contains(., $kw)]
```

returns the same result.

Walking through the desired result:

The first `return` should return every `entry` and its children if the entry's `comment` child contains any of the three keywords in `$pKeywords`.

`concat('!', $kw)` is supposed to make !-containing comments the priority.

The second `return` slices the `comment` and `buyer` nodes from the results of the first `return`.

As long as there is exactly 1 `comment`-named node in every entry, the code executes fine.  When there are 2 or more `comment`-named nodes, the code fails, and the compiler returns the error mentioned above:

`Stopped at line 9, column 22: [XPTY0004] document-node()(...): function(item()*) as item()* expected, document-node() found.`

**-Edit-**

Desired result:

```
<comment>The client is only 20 years old.  Do not be surprised by his youth.</comment>
<buyer/>
<comment>Very personable.  One of our best clients.</comment>
<buyer/>
<comment>!Very difficult to reach, but one of our top buyers.</comment>
<buyer/>
<comment>A bit of an eccentric.  One of our best clients.</comment>
<buyer/>
```

Clarifying the desired result:

```
//contains ! and the first keyword, "best clients"; so, the first result should come from this entry.
  <entry>
    <comment>Very gullible, so please !be sure she needs what you sell her.  She's one of our best clients.</comment>
    <buyer></buyer>
    <id>1523</id>
    <industry>International Trade</industry>
  </entry>

//Only one entry contains ! and "best clients".  So, the first result containing "best clients" contains nodes for the second result.
  <entry>
    <comment>Very personable.  One of our best clients.</comment>
    <buyer></buyer>
    <id>14851</id>
    <industry>Administrative support.</industry>
  </entry>

//This contains ! and the second keyword, "Very", but it is a duplicate.  So, ideally its children should not be returned.
  <entry>
    <comment>!Very difficult to reach, but one of our top buyers.</comment>
    <comment>His wife often answers the phone.  That means he is out of the office.</comment>
    <buyer></buyer>
    <id>1458</id>
    <industry>Construction</industry>
  </entry>

//This contains ! and a string, "very" (part of everything).  Nodes from this entry should be returned as the third result.
  <entry>
    <comment>He wants to buy everything, but !he has a tight budget.</comment>
    <comment>!His company may be closing soon.</comment>
    <buyer></buyer>
    <id>1524</id>
    <industry>Public Relations</industry>
  </entry>

//The only entry whose comment child contains the keyword '20'.  There is no '!'-containing comment with 20, so this nodes is the top and only node whose children should be returned.
  <entry>
    <comment>The client is only 20 years old.  Do not be surprised by his youth.</comment>
    <buyer></buyer>
    <id>1282</id>
    <industry>International Trade; Fish and Game</industry>
  </entry>
```

**-Edit 2-**

Next pass gives a better idea of what I'm trying to accomplish, but there are some obvious syntax errors (for example, I'm still discovering how to work with arrays, as seen on line 8).  I will update this as I resolve the syntax errors:

```
<set>
{
    let $kw := ('best clients', 'Very', '20')
    let $entry := doc('test')/set/entry
    let $priority := '!'

    for $i in (1, count($kw))
    let $priority_result[$i] :=
    (
        for $entries in $entry
        where $entry contains(., $priority) and where $entry contains $kw[$i]
        return subsequence($priority_result[$i], 1, 2)
    )

    if $priority_result[$i] < 2
    for $i in (1, count($kw))
    let $secondary_result[$i] :=
    (
        for $entries in $entry
        where $entry contains $kw[$i] and where $entry not($priority_result) and where $entry not($secondary_result[1..($i-1)])
        return $secondary_result[$i]
    )
    else let $secondary_result[$i] := ''

    for $i in (1, count($kw))
    return
    (
        $primary_result[$i],
        $secondary_result[$i]
    )
}
</set>
```

And the suggested change, which returns a null result:

```
for $doc in doc('test')
let $results :=
(
  let $pKeywords := ('best clients', 'Very', '20')
  return
    for $kw in $pKeywords
    return
    (
      $doc/set/entry/comment[contains(., concat('!', $kw))],
      $doc/set/entry/comment[contains(., $kw)]
    )
  [not(position() gt 2)]
)
for $i in (1 to count($results))
return
(
  subsequence($results/comment, $i, 1),
  subsequence($results/buyer, $i, 1)
)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error message seems to be complaining about trying to call a `document-node()` as a function.

`$doc('test')` vs `$doc`

---

Either that, or `comments(...)` only works for a single node, not a node-set.

`contains(comment, $kw)` vs `comment/contains(.,$kw)`
or `comment[contains(.,$kw)]`
or `comment[contains(text(),$kw)]`

---

This worked for me:

```xquery
<set>{
    for $entry in doc('test')/set/entry
    let $kw := (
        for $prefix in ('!','')
        for $kw in ('best clients', 'Very', '20')
        where exists($entry/comment[contains(., concat($prefix,$kw))])
        return concat($prefix,$kw)
    )[1]
    where exists($kw)
    order by not(starts-with($kw,'!'))
    return <entry keyword="{$kw}">{
      ( $entry/comment,
        $entry/buyer )
    }</entry>
}</set>
```

Result (multiple comments per `<entry>`):

```xml
<set>
   <entry keyword="!Very">
      <comment>!Very difficult to reach, but one of our top buyers.</comment>
      <comment>His wife often answers the phone.  That means he is out of the office.</comment>
      <buyer/>
   </entry>
   <entry keyword="20">
      <comment>The client is only 20 years old.  Do not be surprised by his youth.</comment>
      <buyer/>
   </entry>
   <entry keyword="best clients">
      <comment>Very personable.  One of our best clients.</comment>
      <buyer/>
   </entry>
   <entry keyword="best clients">
      <comment>A bit of an eccentric.  One of our best clients.</comment>
      <buyer/>
   </entry>
   <entry keyword="best clients">
      <comment>Very gullible, so please !be sure she needs what you sell her.  She's one of our best clients.</comment>
      <buyer/>
   </entry>
</set>
```

---

This will give you separate entries for each comment:

```xquery
<set>{
    for $entry in doc('test')/set/entry
    for $comment in $entry/comment
    let $kw := (
        for $prefix in ('!','')
        for $kw in ('best clients', 'Very', '20')
        where exists($comment[contains(., concat($prefix,$kw))])
        return concat($prefix,$kw)
    )[1]
    where exists($kw)
    order by not(starts-with($kw,'!'))
    return <entry keyword="{$kw}">{
      ( $comment,
        $entry/buyer )
    }</entry>
}</set>
```

Output:

```
<set>
   <entry keyword="!Very">
      <comment>!Very difficult to reach, but one of our top buyers.</comment>
      <buyer/>
   </entry>
   <entry keyword="20">
      <comment>The client is only 20 years old.  Do not be surprised by his youth.</comment>
      <buyer/>
   </entry>
   <entry keyword="best clients">
      <comment>Very personable.  One of our best clients.</comment>
      <buyer/>
   </entry>
   <entry keyword="best clients">
      <comment>A bit of an eccentric.  One of our best clients.</comment>
      <buyer/>
   </entry>
   <entry keyword="best clients">
      <comment>Very gullible, so please !be sure she needs what you sell her.  She's one of our best clients.</comment>
      <buyer/>
   </entry>
</set>
```

Comment: If any of the `<entry>` nodes has more than one `<comment>` in it, the script fails; otherwise, the script succeeds.  I'm trying to find a way to execute the script such that it works on `<entry>` nodes with multiple `<comment>` nodes.  Do you think I should include the version without multiple `<comment>` nodes per `<entry>` node, so that people can see the results?

Comment: Could you explain why that works?  It returns `Stopped at line 6, column 20: [XPDY0002] No context item set to process '.'.`, and if you enter `where $entry contains...`, it returns `Stopped at line 6, column 10: [XPST0003] Expecting valid expression after 'where'.`.  I'm testing at basex's live demo: http://basex.org/products/live-demo/

Comment: Ah. I tested with saxon, and it seems to infer the context. Changing `.` to `$c` works better in the BaseX demo.

Comment: I really like that they do that because `.` doesn't say anything to me.  I've found some explanations about it, but it's too dynamic and just seems like an element of a very poorly written language (which isn't typical of XQuery).  Thank you, for noting the change.  It makes it seem much more clear what you have done.  I'm inspecting the results, now.  It seems that you have come very close, but I'm sad to say that the result is incorrect.  The desired result prioritizes entries containing `!`.  They would be at the top of the list.  This is the purpose of the `concat` statements.

Comment: Updated to place `!`-items at the top.

Comment: I went through the desired output entry-by-entry.  Meanwhile, a brief look at your code shows me that there are some things I don't understand: `for $prefix in ('!','')`; why use two `for` clauses back-to-back instead of `for(a,b)`; I thought `concat()` only connected strings back-to-back, so why not use multiple `contains()` clauses, instead; is there something restricting the number of results per keyword, as the initial code; and your `order by` statement says 'not $kw'... what's the logical order?  For example: results by kw, order by !-containing first, then restrict to 2 each/2 each, ..?

Comment: `starts-with()` returns a boolean (with `false` < `true`). If the keyword contains a `!`, it would return `true`. But we want it to be less than if it would *not* contain `!`, so it would come up on top. Thus the `not()` works to swap the order.

Comment: I used two `for` clauses to not have to type as much. It will, for each element in the first `for`-loop, go one revelation in the second `for`-loop. This is effectively the same as `for ($a,$b) in  (('!', 'best clients'), ('!', 'Very'), ... ('', 'best clients'), ('', 'Very'), ...)`

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/17435/discussion-between-wolfpack08-and-markus-jarderot)

Comment: Check out the edits to see some pseudocode.  Meanwhile, the last entry in your answer should be the second entry, I think.

Comment: This can also help to see where I got started and how the error came into play.  Basically, I didn't know that a broader sweep of my xml file would turn up this error, because I didn't expect for there to be multiple comments per entry (an innocent mistake resulting in this complex exception).  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12550694/where-should-i-be-limiting-my-results#comment16917179_12550694 .  Basically, I'm seeking a duplicate result from a different data set, you know?  Switching to `/comment[contains(.,'!')]` etc. returns a blank result. :/

Answer (score 0):

For reference sake, this is the code we start with (it's a little daunting, and I still don't understand it all):

```
for $doc in doc('test')
let $results :=
(
  let $pKeywords := ('best clients', 'Very', '20')
  return
    for $kw in $pKeywords
    return
    (
      $doc/set/entry[contains(comment, concat('!', $kw))],  (: *1 :)
      $doc/set/entry[contains(comment, $kw)]                (: *1 :)
    )
  [not(position() gt 2)]
)
for $i in (1 to count($results))
return
(
  subsequence($results/comment, $i, 1), (: *2 :)
  subsequence($results/buyer, $i, 1)    (: *2 :)
)
```

The version that doesn't throw the error is resolved in the typical way.  It took me a while to catch the second error, marked by `*2`.  Basically, because I was going one level deeper in my search, `*1`, I needed to go up one level for my results, `..`:

```
for $doc in doc('test')
let $results :=
(
  let $pKeywords := ('best clients', 'Very', '20')
  return
    for $kw in $pKeywords
    return
    (
      $doc/set/entry/comment[contains(., concat('!', $kw))], (: *1, went deeper :)
      $doc/set/entry/comment[contains(., $kw)]               (: *1, went deeper :)
    )
  [not(position() gt 2)]
)
for $i in (1 to count($results))
return
(
  subsequence($results/../comment, $i, 1), (: *2, added .. :)
  subsequence($results/../buyer, $i, 1)    (: *2, added .. :)
)
```

What I'm still struggling with:

1) The use of `concat()`.  My understanding is that it puts two things together and its result for `$kw[1]` would be equivalent to `"!best clients"`.  The result doesn't show that, though.  In the result, the exclamation point does not always stand directly before the priority query.

2) Not returning duplicate results.  I'd like every entry to be unique.  I need to add a routine, somewhere, that either restricts duplicates from entering into my result set or that eliminates duplicates prior to `[not(position() gt 2)]`, where the number of results is trimmed/sliced.

Thanks, to all viewers and efforts in the works!  Still looking forward to better answers!