# why can't this javascript code read the csv file

Tags: javascript, csv

I am quite new B in javascript programming and I read the professional javascript for developers book  3rd edition. in addition I have tried many options from the site [How can you read a file line by line in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6861180/how-can-you-read-a-file-line-by-line-in-javascript) or this: [How can you read a file line by line in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6861180/how-can-you-read-a-file-line-by-line-in-javascript).

With the second option I have a problem with understanding what he meant by "file field is rendered" when saying "Remember to put your javascript code after the file field is rendered". Nevertheless I tried it and it didn't work.

Now from my understanding of how file reading works the following code should work but it doesn't, and I don't know why. I hope I am not very boring.

```
<p id="output">
</p>
<form id="form1" action="">
  <input type="file" id="input">
  <input type="button" id="readFil" value="read" onsubmit="readFile()">
</form>
<script>
  function readFile() {
    var selected_file = document.getElementById('input').files[0];
    reader = new FileReader();
    reader.readAsText(selected_file);
    reader.onload = function() {
      document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = reader.result;
    };
  }
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because `input` elements have no `submit` event. `form` elements do. If you want your code called when the button is pressed, use the `click` event.

```
<input type="button" id="readFil" value="read" onclick="readFile()">
<!-- Change is here -----------------------------^^^^^           -->
```