# js can I read a portion of a file with FileReader?

Tags: javascript, filereader

I would like to read a file line by line on a webpage, and the files can be huge.

The file is not on a server but on the client side. I access it with an input-file object.

I know that I could read all the file first, and then split it like on [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6861180/how-can-you-read-a-file-line-by-line-in-javascript) but the issue is that my textfile can really be huge (potentially hundreds of megabytes): I don’t want to fill the RAM.

So is there a way to read a portion of the file, not all the content at once?

Comment: Seems to be possible, but never tried: https://stackoverflow.com/a/28318964/5781499

Comment: Thanks, the slice-way works really well! Maybe I should me marked as a duplicate of this question …